# Postgresql alter table -> add column + values

Tags: postgresql, alter

I need to alter a table in my DB. What I want is to ad a column with type `integer[]` and add values to this column directly from another query which result is 4 id numbers.

What I got currently:

```
ALTER TABLE resourcen add rs_insurance integer[] 
update resourcen set rs_insurance = (select li_id from li_versicherungsart)
```

The second command returns following error :

```
ERROR: column "rs_insurance" is of type integer[] but expression is of type integer
SQL state: 42804
Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
Character: 37
```

How can I cast all IDs found to fit into int[] array?

Comment: `select array_agg(li_id) ...` but you most definitely need some kind of co-related subquery. But it's hard to tell without more detailed information on those two tables and how they relate to each other

Comment: This worked! Posted it as an answer so I can accept it!

Comment: Yes that is exaclty what I want. But the li_versicherungsart is different on different installations.

Comment: Because the values might be changed later on by the user.

Answer (score 4):

You can use postgres array aggregation function:

```
update resourcen set rs_insurance = (select array_agg(li_id) from li_versicherungsart)
```

Reference: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html